# Merging one column in pandas - only keep one row with all values instead of new row for each matc

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two pandas dataframes:

df 1

```
City      | Attraction | X | Z | Y
Somewhere    Rainbows    1   2   3
Somewhere    Trees       4   4   4
Somewhere    Unicorns
```

df 2

```
City      | Other Column | Also another column
Somewhere   Something      Something else
```

Normally this would be done so:

```
df2.merge(df1[['City', 'Attraction']], left_on='City', right_on='City. how='left']

    City      | Other Column | Also another column | Attraction
Somewhere   Something      Something else              Rainbows
Somewhere   Something      Something else              Trees
Somewhere   Something      Something else              Unicorns
```

However, I would like to group the results of the join into a comma separated list (or whatever):

```
City      | Other Column | Also another column  | Attraction
Somewhere   Something      Something else         Rainbows, Trees, Unicorns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby()` and `map`:

```
df2['Attaction'] = df2['City'].map(df1.groupby('City').Attraction.agg(', '.join))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I am about to flag this as solved, but one caveat, what if the joined df has several similar rows, f.ex with "rainbows" - won't then the new "attraction" column containt several of that attraction?

Comment: IIUC, if your df2 has several rows with same city, then yes, same list of attractions is copied to all those rows.